# What is the proper way doing *ngfor?

Tags: angular, ngfor

Hi Could someone tell me how to do ***ngFor** properly?

**Error:**

> Type '{ colorways: { thumbnail: string[]; thumbnailWithAvatar:
> string[]; patternLayoutThumbnailWithFabricMark: string; name: string;
> thumbnailWithFabricMark: string[]; thumbnailPattern: string[];

```
export interface Pokedex {
  colorways: Colorway[];
  count: number;
}

export interface Colorway {
  thumbnail: string[];
  name: string;
  id: number;
  uuid: string;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="item-list" * ngFor="let item of imgSource?.colorways">
  {{ item.thumbnail[0] }}
</div>
```

[Stackblitz - repro](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7skqzr)

I'm trying to bind only **0th** index of **thumbnail[0]** and **name** from API response.

Thanks all

Comment: The error is not related to the *ngFor but to your use of the interfaces. Your assignment is not matching the Pokédex interface definition (you're missing the other thumbnail variables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you've put the wrong variable here, your 'item' array is empty but you're trying to iterate on it. If you switch with 'data' constant which has your data, it works fine :

```
<div class="item-list" * ngFor="let item of data.colorways">
  {{ item.thumbnail[0] }}
</div>
```

Note: There was wrong interfaces issues in the code, I've updated it in [your Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-utdpzu?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with for loop (just data?.colorways). Error is occurring due to the wrong interface. The interface is missing few items for `Colorway`.

```
export interface Colorway {
  thumbnail: string[];
  thumbnailWithAvatar: string[];
  patternLayoutThumbnailWithFabricMark: string;
  thumbnailWithFabricMark: string[];
  thumbnailPattern: string[];
  thumbnailWithTrimMark: string[];
  patternLayoutThumbnailWithTrimMark: string;
  name: string;
  id: number;
  uuid: string;
}
```

and data will be

```
data: Pokedex
```

But you have assigned it as array. Check this out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rfqs1z?file=src/app/app.component.ts